# drop down menu in Grails

Tags: grails, menu

I am working on my first Grails project, using grails 3.0.3. I want to add a drop down menu to my application. I searched the web and found some plugins that are deprecated and been told to use grails platform-core plugin. However I am not able to use this plugin in grails 3.0.3. What I did:

1/ added the folling dependency to build.gradle: 
    compile "org.grails.plugins:platform-core"

2/ added some nav to layout main.gsp

```
<nav:primary/>
<nav:secondary/>
<div id="user-nav">
   <nav:menu scope="user"/>
</div>
```

3/ Compiled: fine

4/ run: got a null pointer exception (classpath not find)

When I remove the compile "org.grails.plugins:platform-core" dependency, the application works fine.

What to do ? Is there a better solution than plateform-core?

Comment: As @Uday says, it sounds more like a front end thing. Do you want to build your menu dynamically from your domain? In any case, patform core is probably overkill if all you want is a menu. Maybe checkout something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) if all you want is some nicely styled HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the menus on your HTML/gsp?

It looks more related to HTML/CSS that needs to be added to gsp file. I don't think you need any plugin for this.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your answers. I come from the JSF world and though there were some gsp tags for laying out menus, static menus. It is also nice to just use html+css, as this is more flexible.